# How to remove double opacity caused by use of pseudo elements

Tags: css, opacity, pseudo-element, overlapping

I am using pseudo elements to dynamically draw segments of circles. My problem is now that I want to use opacity of 0.7 but when the elements are overlapping the opacity is higher. What can I do to have the same opacity for the overlapping parts? Is there a way to style them?

I am using styled components but the static version looks like this:

```css
.circle {
  background-color: #d6dadc;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.circle_segment {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: undefined;
  background-color: rgba(75, 0, 250, 0.7);
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
}

.circle_segment:before {
  height: 100%;
  content: " ";
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(75, 0, 250, 0.7);
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform: translate(0%, -100%) rotate(-90deg)
}

.circle_segment:after {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(75, 0, 250, 0.7);
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="circle_segment" />
  </div>
</body>
```

If someone had an idea, I would be happy to know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi! Can you, please, create a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so we can see the actual problem and copy it to an answer easily? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see the problem now. If you don't want specific elements to be partially opaque between them but want to be partially opaque with the rest, I recommend to add all those elements inside another element and use the `opacity` CSS property. Because `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements are already inside its "parent" element, you can simply modify the parent opacity, like so:

```css
.circle {
  background-color: #d6dadc;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.circle_segment {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: undefined;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: rgb(75, 0, 250);
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
}

.circle_segment:before {
  height: 100%;
  content: " ";
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(75, 0, 250);
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform: translate(0%, -100%) rotate(-90deg)
}

.circle_segment:after {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(75, 0, 250);
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
}
.wildelement {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 190px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 450px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="wildelement"></div>
    <div class="circle_segment" />
  </div>
</body>
```